# Exporting planet.osm.pbf into PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, osm2pgsql

could someone help with this? I found only this: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql
and this:
http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm2pgsql/ but
windows binary was removed, and I never use cygwin or linux bash.

Actually I've installed Postgresql with postgis, and downloaded planet.osm.pbf.

I need some advice how to proceed with Osm2pgsql, wich will be helpful for newbie. Thanks

Comment: As your first link states, use cygwin. Or use Linux.

Comment: I have requirement Windows :/

Comment: Cygwin is a Linux-like environment for Windows

Comment: I know but I was not successful with him ... do you know any simpler solution for windows?

Comment: No. Get used to cygwin. Or install a Linux VM inside your Windows host. This will have a negative impact on performance of course.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import OSM file to PostGis on Windows10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910763/import-osm-file-to-postgis-on-windows10)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest running a an Ubuntu Server (14.04 or 16.04) and following the instructions here:

https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/

You can run this on a Virtualbox from your windows machine.

The reason I suggest this is that you will only make things more difficult for yourself trying to install on windows.

I myself was completely new to Linux before I installed my MapServer, and I found it really easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Osmosis can also do imports of osm (pbf) file to postgres DB with postgis extension. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis