# Routing network from OSM

Tags: postgresql, routes, openstreetmap, postgis, geoserver

I'm looking for some good tool to import map.osm to postgres and next create some routes which will be displayed by geoserver. I need route, with some text information about vertexes (e.g. city, address, address number, and so on...)

I found this:

**osm2pgrouting** - Import OSM data into pgRouting Database
**osm2postgis** -Import OSM data to PostGIS
**osm2po** - tool to convert OSM data into a routable format
**osm4routing** - OpenStreetMap data parser to turn them into a nodes-edges adapted for routing applications

I do not have many experiences with GIS, so how tool is the best for me? I try osm2pgrouting, but in result I have tables, which do not contains data about vertexes(only lat. and alt.) Thanks for answers.
**UPDATE** App Info:
I will be have web and android client where user enter text value of start and end node, and next over geoserver get wms with vertexes of entered route for example
                                                                                                 My result from could be be some edges and nodes like this like this:
sequence_num, edge_distance, and informations about edge vertexes like osm_id, some text value, lat alt, etc...

Comment: Ok, all those tools will produce data, but how do you want to use the data? which kind of routing application will you use? Add this information to the question.

Comment: I update my question, can you check this please?

Comment: It's still unclear what your end app will be. On the client side WMS is an image and is not suitable to return edges and nodes. What exactly are you returning - a picture, a list, both, or what? Similarly what, exactly, is the user entering? clicking / tapping on a map (i.e. coordinates), typing in addresses, or selecting a node id (presumably with a description)? Are you e.g. using Leaflet or OpenLayers in your client?

Comment: try imagine some road with nodes, where road is bending ... and this is what I need ... information about edges between these nodes like max speed, road type, and information about node for example if it city so name for example ... but informations about nodes are more important for me I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a lot of work to do before you get to a complete solution, but here are some pointers. I suggest you break down your project into smaller chunks and ask specific questions on any bits you might get stuck on.

First, you need to import your data. Then you'll need some pre-processing / cleaning. Then you need your routing queries and, finally, a way to use the outputs (with this last part determining to some extent the previous steps).

### Import OSM data

As I described in an answer to your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910763/import-osm-file-to-postgis-on-windows10?rq=1), you can use OGR2OGR to import OSM data to Postgis. You can use other programs, as you mention above, but I guess you'll get much the same results. I think the difference between the OGR2OGR tables and the osm2postgis ones is that some of the columns in the latter appear in the other_tags column. However, the data is still there, you just need slightly different queries.

### Preparing data

I'm assuming you'll use [pgrouting](http://pgrouting.org/) for the routing, but whatever you use, you'll need a network suitable for routing (in short, the edges have a start and end node, and the end nodes must connect with other start nodes). Pgrouting has tools to create what you need and validate it. E.g. you create integer columns `source` and `target` and the function `pgr_createtopology` will populate the columns for you.

OGR2OGR gives you tables "lines", "points", "multipolygons", "multilinestrings". I suggest you read up on OSM to understand exactly what is in these tables, but, roughly speaking, the lines contain your roads and the multipolygons contain, amongst other things, buildings with e.g. addresses. The addresses are in a [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) column called "other_tags".

The lines do not contain addresses! (although they do contain street names). So, if you want to do address-to-address routing you need to do some preparation. You can skip this if you can live with the street names.

- Create your network (e.g. if you're routing for cars, you'll want to
  throw out pedestrian routes and so on)
- Extract the desired addresses (including coordinates)
- Either [snap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180285/snapping-line-nodes-to-points) the addresses to the nearest    node, or otherwise
  relate the address to the nearest node

Pgrouting will return the edges in your route, so you need the above to relate back to your addresses.

### Routing

Your app is going to send to your server (in an as-yet unspecified way) a pair of addresses or coordinates and you need postgis to return the route. With pgrouting, that's quite easy and there are plenty of examples out there, for example [here](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/chapters/shortest_path.html#pgr-dijkstra). You will need to write queries that join the output to your address table to give you the desired output.

pgrouting creates a vertices table. You can get the nearest vertex with the following query:

```
select id from vertices_pgr
order by the_geom <-> st_setsrid(st_point(lon,lat),4326)
limit 1
```

### Using the output

Using WMS from geoserver is unlikely to be a good choice - you won't have the information on individual edges without a lot of messing about. You might consider [geoJSON](http://geojson.org/), which can be read by e.g. OpenLayers, Leaflet, or you can manipulate in Javascript. Postgres has lots of useful functions for working with json and geojson.

### Conclusion

That's quite a lot of work and probably new stuff if you have little GIS knowledge, and it, er, basically recreates what you'd get from Graphhopper! Are you sure that's not a better way to go?

If you do decide to go this (or similar) route break things down into manageable chunks! First, figure out exactly what you're trying to achieve, then work backwards from there. If you do decide to use OSM / pgrouting, then play with the data and pgrouting first so you understand how it works before trying address matching etc.

Comment: Thanks for a detail answer I have some question so I split it for your parts:
Import OSM: so if I'm not wrong, this tool provide me general data from OSM file. Result that you describe looks same as result from osm2pgsql right?
Preparing data: Can I use pgrouting for this data which I have, or I could create new tables over osm2pgrouting?
Output: User enter 2 strings (point from and to), can you give me some hint how get coordinates or osm_id of this points? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Hi, studied some materials, and I hit on a problem. A lot of tutorials solve displaying baselayer downloading from osm server over some framework (e.g. OpenLayers3). Is possible send base layer over geoserver over tiles without downloading from external servers on client? Thanks for answer

Comment: It's possible to server a baselayer (as wms) from your own geoserver using the data you download to the server, yes. But you'd need to style and configure the data (in postgis and geoserver) essentially to duplicate what you'd get with one line of code from Openlayers.

Comment: I have no choice because it is my task from job :/  Can you give me some specifically hints where I can found needed materials for this stuff?

Comment: You need to search on "OSM Style" e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86802/how-can-i-style-osm-data-in-geoserver

Comment: I looking some solutions and I hit to solution to download tiles .. is it good or style layers are better solution? What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

The tools you listed are only for producing data, but I think you actually need a routing engine.
Try Graphhopper: https://graphhopper.com

Using the WEB Api (more likely what you need), you don't need the import the data in your database. This is the easiest solution. You will have not control over the input openstreetmap data but this is fine if you don't have special requirements.

Import data and implement/integrate a routing engine directly in your application would be much more complicated.

Comment: I know graphhopper but my task is create that application, will be works offline

Comment: This is a very important information and should be added to the question

Comment: But, this does not make sense: you can not build a android application which uses a Postgres database and works offline. Not to mention the web client...

Comment: it was not very good explanation ... with "offline" I mean that, wms will be the only service, what client call to display map (nothing else) .. it not my idea ... I got that task :(

Comment: GraphHopper runs offline on Android and iOS too.